# xbuf_frurl does not work properly without server header of content length?

Tags: http-headers, client, g-wan

I try to get some info from other sites with xbuf_frurl.
I got some site OK but some Not OK.

By Now, I still can not make sure what is going wrong.
But some sites are missing the content length header.

Who can tell whether `xbuf_frurl()` relies on the (potentially missing) content length header, esp. when growing the buffer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xbuf_frurl()` is indeed reading a body IF an HTTP content-length header is present. It will not try to decode chunked responses.

To deal with those servers using chunked replies, use the [G-WAN curl.c example](http://gwan.ch/source/curl.c) provided with the distribution. With `libcurl` you have even the opportunity to use SSL/TLS.

If that's not resolving your problem, the only way to troubleshoot this kind of issues is to give a non-working example, with both the full request that you have sent and the full reply received from the server.

That's why the `xbuf_xcat("%v")` format has been added: to give hexdumps, even with binary replies.

Edit your question and add this information to let people help you with a well-defined problem.